# Using Generics on Classes with Static DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, devexpress-wpf

We are looking at creating a helper class for validation on a DevExpress WPF application single view model.

In our xaml, we want to add a reference to our ValidationServiceHelper class:

```
<dxlc:DataLayoutControl x:Name="layoutControlMyObject" Style="{StaticResource EntityView.DataLayoutControl}"
    viewmodel:ValidationServiceHelper.HasErrors="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(dxe:ValidationService.HasValidationError)}">
```

The ValidationServiceHelper class looks like this:

```
namespace MyApplication.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MyObjectViewModel : 
        SingleObjectViewModel<MyObject, int, IMyEntityUnitOfWork>
    {
        // ...
    }

    public class ValidationServiceHelper
    {
        public static bool GetHasErrors(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(HasErrorsProperty);
        }

        public static void SetHasErrors(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(HasErrorsProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorsProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HasErrors", typeof(bool), 
            typeof(ValidationServiceHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnHasErrorsChanged));

        private static void OnHasErrorsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)d;
                element.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
                    ((MyObjectViewModel)element.DataContext).ViewHasErrors = (bool)e.NewValue));
                var err = ValidationService.GetValidationErrors(d);
                if (err != null)
                    element.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
                        ((MyObjectViewModel)element.DataContext).ViewErrors = 
                    err.Select(p => p.ErrorContent).Distinct().Aggregate(
                    (j, i) => string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", i, Environment.NewLine, j)).ToString()));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the two Dispatcher.BeginInvoke calls in OnHasErrorsChanged, you will see I hard-coded a cast to MyObjectViewModel.

```
element.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    ((MyObjectViewModel)element.DataContext).ViewHasErrors = (bool)e.NewValue));
```

Written like this, I would need to create a different helper class. Is there a way to make this generic, so I can only use one class for all my view models?

Answer (score 0):

You could derive your view model classes from a common base class (or implement an interface) where the `ViewErrors` property is defined and cast to this type:

```
var vm = element.DataContext as BaseViewModel;
if  (vm != null)
    element.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => vm.ViewHasErrors = (bool)e.NewValue));
```

But you will never be able to cast the `DataContext` to any other type than the actual type of the object in memory. Using generics one way or another doesn't change this fact.

And there is no way to cast a `SingleObjectViewModel<A, int, IMyEntityUnitOfWork>` to a `SingleObjectViewModel<B, int, IMyEntityUnitOfWork>` because these are two totally different types.

Comment: I believe ViewErrors is part of the base class, SingleObjectViewModel; however, that class requires three type arguments to be used to indicate which EF model it is using.

Comment: Move the property to a non-generic base class of the generic one, or implement an interface and cast to this one.

Comment: As I said, there is no way to cast a SingleObjectViewModel<A, int, IMyEntityUnitOfWork> to a SingleObjectViewModel<B, int, IMyEntityUnitOfWork> because these are two totally different types. It is like trying to cast an int to a Button and will always fail. Two instances of a generic type that has different type parameters are two totally different types. The generic definition itself is *not* some kind of a base class for all generic types.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I had thought about implementing an interface with the ViewHasErrors and use it in my helper class.

Comment: In your helper class? This won't let you access the property of the view model.

Comment: I may not have worded my last comment very well. I'm thinking I would make the SingleObjectViewModel implement my interface and change the casting on my helper to cast to the interface. I'm making the adjustment on my program now to see how it works. If it does, I'll post my changes as an answer.

Comment: So you are doing as I suggested then? Why don't you accept my answer instead of posting your own copy of it?